# passing argument 1 of ' 'makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, header-files

I am currently working on an AUTOSAR project and hence the code generated is based on that particular software and may look slightly odd. But the file First.c is completley C. My question is regarding accessing the value stored in a pointer variable in C.

I have a header file 'header.h' that refrences to a function and looks something like below. THis header file further accesses a seperate function from another file.

header.h

```
 static inline Std_ReturnType First_Element(uint32 *data){
      return First_Element_Read(data);
 }
```

This function is called in the c file 'First.c' as follows.

```
 int x;
 int result;
 void Func_call(void){

      result = First_Element(x);
      printf("The value in result is %d", &result);

      return 0;
 }
```

I just want to access the value from the variable 'data' there in the header file into the x variable in the C file. When I do it this way I get an warning saying

**passing argument 1 of 'First_Element' from incompatible pointer type.**
and no data is displayed. Could somebody kindly point out my mistake here.

Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: Just look at your own code for five seconds. `int` is not `uint32_t*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`First_Element` takes an argument of type `uint32 *`.

You call it with an argument of type `int`.

These don't match, so it doesn't work. It's hard to see what you expected to happen here, so I can't really suggest a fix.

---

Update: The corrected code should be:

```
 uint32 x;                                           /* <--- note type */
 Std_ReturnType result;                              /* <--- note type */
 void Func_call(void){

      result = First_Element(&x);                    /* <--- added "&" */
      printf("The value in result is %d", result);

      return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What I expect to happen here is that the value from the variable data is got into the variable x in the C file. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Ah, so `First_element` is supposed to write something back into that argument?

Comment: 1.) Declare `x` of the correct type (`uint32`) -- 2.) pass a *pointer to `x`* (`&x`) as the function expects

Comment: `printf` is also incorrect, probably don't want to print the address of the result. Also, there's no telling which is the correct conversion specifier for `Std_ReturnType`.

Comment: @Lundin You're probably right, but as you say, I don't actually know that.

Answer (score 1):

you should be passing correct, properly typecasted value

```
   result = First_Element((uint32 *) &x);
```

also better to re think on the declaration of x as signed int

```
int x;
```

and probably you might want to change the below from

```
 printf("The value in result is %d", &result);
```

to

```
 printf("The value in result is %d", result);
```